# $event.stopPropagation() doesn't seem to prevent a directive in a parent element from receiving the event [Angular][routerLink][Directive]

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, stoppropagation, angular-routerlink

**EDIT:** found out what was wrong; read the solution below.

I wrote a directive to open the link in a new tab, and it's working wonderfully.

The problem is when I put it in a table that has a link in the entire row, and an event listener in a specific cell that should not activate the link and call a function, but it captures the event and activates the link even though I called `$event.stopPropagation` in said function.

In this example, clicking in the first row doesn't trigger `routerLink`, but the second triggers routing:

```html
<table>
  <tr [routerLink]="'other'">
    <td><p (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">Hello</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr [appNewTab]="'other'">
    <td><p (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">Hello</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Directive code:

```ts
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appNewTab]',
})
export class NewTabDirective {
  @Input() appNewTab = '/';

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  private get url(): string {
    return window.location.href + '/' + this.appNewTab;
  }

  @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
  onClick($event: MouseEvent) {
    if ($event.ctrlKey || $event.metaKey || $event.button === 1) {
      window.open(this.url, '_blank');
    } else if ($event.button === 0) {
      this.router.navigate([this.appNewTab], { relativeTo: this.route });
    }
  }
}
```

[Run in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ef7u9r?file=src/app/app.component.html) (updated with working example)

---

ps.: I'm also using `$event.preventDefault()`, but I don't think it matters in this specific case.

ps2.: I put both `$event.preventDefault()` and `$event.stopPropagation()` inside the directive's `onClick` method, but I don't think it matters too.

---

**SOLUTION**

The issue was that I was listening to the `mousedown` event, but the `click` event is different, so calling `stopPropagation` inside it wouldn't stop the propagation of the `click` event after the user released the mouse button.

I changed it from `click` to `mousedown` because the `click` event only fires with the left button mouse, and I needed to listen to the middle mouse button clicks.

The solution was to separate the `HostListener` in two:

```ts
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appNewTab]',
})
export class NewTabDirective {
  @Input() appNewTab = '/';

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  private get url(): string {
    return window.location.href + '/' + this.appNewTab;
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick($event: MouseEvent) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    if ($event.ctrlKey || $event.metaKey) {
      window.open(this.url, '_blank');
    } else {
      this.router.navigate([this.appNewTab], { relativeTo: this.route });
    }
  }

  @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
  onMouseDown($event: MouseEvent) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    if ($event.button === 1) {
      window.open(this.url, '_blank');
    }
  }
}
```